# Update entity framework 5, one to one relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
public class Card : EntityBase
{
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(16)]
    [RegularExpression("([0-9]+)", ErrorMessage = "Only number allowed")]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}

public class Customer : EntityBase
{
    public Customer()
    {
        Address = new Address();
    }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Card")]
    public int Card_Id { get; set; }

    public Card Card { get; set; }
}

public class CustomerConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public CustomerConfiguration()
    {
        HasRequired(x => x.Card).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.Card_Id);
    }
}

static void CreateCustomer()
    {
        using (var context = new BenzineFleetContext())
        {
            var card = var card = new Card
                           {
                               Number = "123456"
                           };
            context.Cards.Add(card);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }

        using (var context = new BenzineFleetContext())
        {
            var card = context.Cards.First(c => c.Number == "123456");

            var customer = new Customer { Name = "Rayz", Card = card };
            context.Customers.Add(customer);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I want to create new Customer and use card from database, when i save to database, Card_Id in table Customer is exist, but Customer_Id in table Card is null. How to update Customer_Id in table card?

Sorry my english is bad :(
Thanks for help :)

Comment: seems like you're adding a new card, then adding a customer to the card

Comment: if i add a new card, then will be two object card in database.

Comment: yes, but you are creating a new card.

Comment: I want to use an existing card in database, not make a new card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
using (var context = new BenzineFleetContext())
{
    var card = context.Cards.First(c => c.Number == "123456");

    var customer = new Customer { Name = "Rayz", Card = card };
    card.Customer = customer;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```